# <c: choose> condition in jsp executes all conditions

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, if-statement, el

I am trying to make a simple MySQL, Java JDBC  web app in Netbeans.
I wish to display different stuff depending on a status variable in the current session. I have tried the following method:

Firstly I have the following code in a .jsp page:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${sessionScope.Staff.getStatus() == staff.default_staff_status}">Default staff</c:when>
    <c:when test="${sessionScope.Staff.getStatus() == staff.financial_staff_status}">Financial staff</c:when>
    <c:when test="${sessionScope.Staff.getStatus() == staff.legal_staff_status}">Legal staff</c:when>
    <c:otherwise>Secretarial staff</c:otherwise> 
</c:choose>
```

And secondly I have the following code in a .jsp page:

```
<c:if test = "${sessionScope.Staff.getStatus() == Staff.default_staff_status}" >
    Default staff
</c:if> 
<c:if test = "${sessionScope.Staff.getStatus() == Staff.financial_staff_status}" >
    Financial staff
</c:if> 
<c:if test = "${sessionScope.Staff.getStatus() == Staff.legal_staff_status}" >
    Legal staff
</c:if> 
<c:if test = "${sessionScope.Staff.getStatus() == Staff.secretarial_staff_status}" >
    Secretarial staff
</c:if>
```

sessionScope.Staff gives an object StaffData defined as:

```
public class StaffData 
{
    protected final byte default_staff_status = 0;
    protected final byte financial_staff_status = 1;
    protected final byte legal_staff_status = 2;
    protected final byte secretarial_staff_status = 3;

    private byte status;
    //Other data

    StaffData()
    {
        //Constructor
    }

    //Other methods

    public byte getStatus()
    {
        return this.status;
    }

    public byte getDefault_staff_status()
    {
        return this.default_staff_status;
    }

    public byte getFinancial_staff_status()
    {
        return this.financial_staff_status;
    }

    public byte getLegal_staff_status()
    {
        return this.legal_staff_status;
    }

    public byte getSecretarial_staff_status()
    {
        return this.secretarial_staff_status;
    }
}
```

By both methods, my output is:

```
    Default staff Financial staff Legal staff Secretarial staff
```

However, only one of them should have been printed. All the getter functions are public and properly defined. Why am I seeing all the lines being printed?

Related earlier question: [JSP-EL session variable access error: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException despite said property being public](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27054792/jsp-el-session-variable-access-error-javax-el-propertynotfoundexception-despite)

Comment: Seems that you haven't applied the solution provided there.

Comment: I did put in the test attribute. I didnt change sessionScope.Staff.getStatus() to Staff.status, because I want to explicitly state that I am using a session variable. I also added the getter method for Financial_staff_status. However, how does that explain the output I am getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out my mistake.
I had forgotten to include :

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

Dont know why I didnt get any error for this